Combinatorics question and how to approach it
I always struggle on these sorts of questions:
Question: A dealer is dealing a deck with 12 cards to 4 players. The deck consists of 4 Kings, 4 Queens, and 4 Jacks. What is the probability that every person receives the same hand of 1 of each card?
These are all the ways I have tried to solve it - would you guys be able to help me in terms of where I am going wrong:
Method 1 -

Let's start off with the kings. There are $4$ kings to choose from and 4 groups to put them in so that is $4^2$.
Then there are $3$ kings to choose from and $3$ groups to put them into so that is $3^2$.
Continuing like this for the kings, we get $4^2 * 3^2 * 2^2 * 1^2$. So repeating for the queens and jacks, we get the numerator as $(4^2 * 3^2 * 2^2 * 1^2)^2$
Using similar logic, the denominator is $12^{12}$ since there are 12 cards to choose from and 12 positions to put them in.
So I get (the wrong answer of) $\frac{(4^2 * 3^2 * 2^2 * 1^2)^2}{12^{12}}$

Given that method 1 didn't work I tried this:
Method 2 -
(I decided to scrap the choosing out of the $4$ kings at the start, simply because I got the question wrong but I don't understand why this is wrong).

The first king has $4$ choices of the group it can go in.
The second king has $3$ choices of the group it can go in.
Continuing this we get for the kings $4!$ combinations. Repeating for queens and jacks, we get $4!^3$ as the numerator.
The denominator is now only $12!$ since there are $12$ possibilities for the first card, $11$ possible positions for the second card, etc, giving an answer of $\frac{4!^3}{12!}$, which is again wrong.

Method 3: I think what was wrong with method 2 was that the numerator was not taking into account the order of the cards within each group but the denominator was. So the denominator should be $\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$. This gives me the correct answer of $\frac{72}{1925}$.
But what I get confused with is here are we treating the kings/queens/jacks as being different and how do we know that? How would we work this question out if we didn't distinguish between the kings/queens/jacks - would it be to divide both top and bottom by $4!^3$? Also how do we know that we have labelled or unlabelled the groups - would it be true that if we had unlablled the groups then we would need to divide by $3!$ and how would we know that? I am only able to do it because I now know the answer, but what is the thinking behind it?
Also does anyone have any tips on how to get better at combinatorics apart from practice? I always have to think long and hard to spot overcounting or thinking about ordered vs unordered in my strategies and sometimes I miss them entirely which isn't ideal for an interview situation.
I know it's a lot of questions and I am not expecting any of you to answer all of them (although that would be nice :) ), but I just get frustrated when I keep on getting these type of questions wrong.

The problem statement requires that we treat all cards of the same rank as indistinguishable (else no two people could have the same hand).  To solve it, I suggest counting the total number of possible deals and then count those deals in which each person gets exactly one of each rank.

Worth noting:  the method I sketched is often applicable.  Count what you can count!  Don't worry if it isn't exactly what was asked.  Worst case, you get used to the relevant combinatorics.

$\left(\frac{12}{12} \times \frac{8}{11}  \times \frac{4}{10} \right) \times \left(\frac{9}{9} \times \frac{6}{8}  \times \frac{3}{7} \right) \times \left(\frac{6}{6} \times \frac{4}{5}  \times \frac{2}{4} \right) \times \left(\frac{3}{3} \times \frac{2}{2}  \times \frac{1}{1} \right)$ works for me.  This is $\dfrac{(4!)^3 \times (3!)^4}{12!}=\dfrac{72}{1925}$.

Your general strategy for this type of problem is good - you want to think about constructing the deals. Then, you need to keep in mind what features of the construction are important - e.g., do we care about the specific order of cards in a hand? (Here, no.) Do we care about which hand goes to which player? (Here, yes.) Then, count, making sure that you maintain consistency with those features.
How many total ways are there to deal? Suppose the players are $A, B, C, D$, and we give out the cards in that order. There are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to create the hand for $A$. Then, there are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to create the hand for $B$. And so on. The total number of distinct outcomes is therefore $\binom{12}{3} \binom{9}{3} \binom{6}{3}$.
Now, we want to count the number of "successful" deals. Since each person must get one of each value, we can think about forming $3$ lines: one of $J$, one of $Q$, and one of $K$, permuting them, and then handing them out to each player. There are $4!$ ways to permute a single line, so there are $(4!)^3$ to permute all $3$ lines.
Therefore, the desired probability is
$$P = \frac{(4!)^3}{\binom{12}{3} \binom{9}{3} \binom{6}{3}} = \boxed{\frac{72}{1925}}$$
What went wrong with your first two methods?

There are $4$ kings to choose from and $4$ groups to put them in so that is $4^2$.

This is OK so far.

Then there are $3$ kings to choose from and $3$ groups to put them into so that is $3^2$.

The issue starts here. Imagine for a second we have $K_1, K_2, K_3, K_4$ as the four kings. In the first step, let's say that $K_1$ and player $A$ were chosen. In the second step, let's say that $K_2$ and player $B$ were chosen. Then at this point, $A$ has $K_1$ and $B$ has $K_2$. It's also possible, however, that in the first step, $K_2$ and player $B$ were chosen, and in the second step, $K_1$ and player $A$ were chosen, and this gives the same result. So, you are overcounting. And the same goes for the rest of the count.
There is nothing particularly bad about this approach, per se, but you do need to correct for the overcount. It is easy in this case, since after giving out all four kings, we know that each distribution could have happened in $4!$ ways (and every single one of these were counted). So just divide through to get
$$\frac{(4!)^2}{4!} = 4!$$
ways to distribute kings. The same goes for handing out $Q$ and $J$, so you end up with $(4!)^3$ "successful" deals (which is exactly what we got before).

Using similar logic, the denominator is $12^{12}$ since there are $12$ cards to choose from and $12$ positions to put them in.

I cannot understand this point at all. First, once you assign a card to a "slot", that slot is no longer available in the future. So first, we should have something like $12!$. Then, recall that we don't care about the order of a hand - if we did, our count for the "successful" deals would have needed to consider that as well, which it did not. So, once again, we need to correct for overcount, which we can do simply by noticing that for each player, there are $3!$ ways to arrange their hand, for $(3!)^4$ ways for all players (and every single one of these were counted). So, the denominator should be
$$\frac{12!}{(3!)^4}$$
which you will find is exactly equal to $\binom{12}{3} \binom{9}{3} \binom{6}{3}$ as we calculated before.

Thank you for the answer. It really clarified a lot of things. I understand that the $12^{12}$ was silly. Just one question - how do you figure out so quickly that I was overcounting? Is it because for the questions where you have grouped objects (in this case they are the kings, queens and jacks) you will always overcount if you use a strategy like i did?

@Apex345 Glad that it helped! It is usually easy to spot overcounting when you have a situation where you do not care about order (or assignment), but are counting with order (or assignment) in mind. For example, if we are taking $2$ marbles out of a jar with $N$ distinct marbles, and we don't care about the order that those marbles are drawn (just what "combination" we get), then we might start by saying, there are $N$ choices for the first marble and $N - 1$ choices for the second marble, giving $N (N - 1)$. ...

... But notice that first and second is not important, and each combination was counted twice (e.g., $AB$ and $BA$). So we need to divide by $2$ to get the correct answer, $\frac{N (N - 1)}{2}$. (This process of selecting a subset from a set is so common that we usually just use the binomial coefficient $\binom{N}{2}$.)
